# How many solutions does the ODE have?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The question :**
Given ODE :
$$
\begin{cases}
y'-a^2(y')^3-\frac{\sin(x)}{x+y}=0 \\
y(0)=1
\end{cases}
$$
Write how many solutions does the system have for $a=0$ and $a \ne 0$.

**My try :**
for $a=0$ we have a unique solution by Picard's theorem.
In the case where $a \ne 0$ I'm stuck and can't understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a\ne 0$, your first equation is a cubic equation in $y'$. So you have three roots:
$$y'_{1,2,3}=f_{1,2,3}(x,y(x))$$
For each root you have a unique solution (Picard–Lindelöf theorem). All you need to show is that your roots are different. Start from the [cubic roots formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula).

Comment: You could also just look at the case for the initial point, the solutions of $y'-a^2(y')^3=0$ can be found directly.

Comment: Before I posted the question I found some solutions but couldn't really guess the number of them. they were $y=1 , y'=\frac{1}{a} \rightarrow y'=\frac{1}{a}x+1$ and  $y'=- \frac{-1}{a} \rightarrow y=\frac{-1}{a}x+1$. I tried to plug the solutions but I received false statement on the $\frac{sin(x)}{x+y}$

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann , I am not convinced that the solutions for the ode you wrote - are the solutions for the main ode.

Comment: @Roach87: You have to argue further: as you get isolated roots for $y'$ at $(x,y)=(0,1)$, you can apply the implicit function theorem to get local explicit equations $y'=f(x,y)$. By the same theorem and its corollaries this equation is smooth, thus giving a local and unique solution of the ODE. A direct symbolic solution is highly unlikely, I would say impossible.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Makes sense yet complicated :). so the point in these sort of questions is to look for roots of the homogeneous ode and then solve for the roots ?

Comment: @Roach87: There is nothing special "homogeneous" in this equation, just the fact that $\sin(0)=0$. If the initial point was elsewhere, you would get a constant term in the cubic equation, and no "nice" explicit solutions.